# How to solve a "1 producer 2 consumers" problem in java

Tags: java, buffer, consumer, producer

I am pretty new in writing Java and i'm currently trying to implement a different aspect of the classic "Producer-Consumer" problem. I still use one Producer like usual, who writes strings in a buffer. This buffer is shared with the 2 Consumer threads, and what I am trying to do is to have both the Consumers pick up EVERY string the producer sends, and ONLY then delete the string from the buffer. How can i check if both the Consumer threads have already taken the string??? Thank you!

Comment: Lets take a look at how kafka topics or rabbitmq fanout exchanges works. You can implement an in memory very basic version of them.

Comment: I think this wouldn't really be producer-consumer anymore, then. It would be a lot more complicated than just filling two queues, one for each of these distinct consumers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use the observer pattern.

More info: https://www.baeldung.com/java-observer-pattern